# Why once we override service(), delegation never gets to doGet()?

Tags: servlets

After I make a GET request to the following servlet, the text 'In service method' is written and can not explain it. why is that?

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
   public void service(HttpServletRequest req,
                       HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
      Writer out = resp.getWriter();
      out.write("In Service method");
   }

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
                                                        throws IOException {
      Writer out = resp.getWriter();
      out.write("In get method");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of [`HttpServlet#service()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) does [**exactly**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) that job. Here's an extract of its javadoc:

> Receives standard HTTP requests from the public service method and dispatches them to the `doXXX` methods defined in this class. This method is an HTTP-specific version of the `Servlet.service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest, javax.servlet.ServletResponse)` method. There's no need to override this method.

It delegates to the appropriate servlet method depending on the HTTP method. E.g. when `request.getMethod()` equals to `"GET"`, then it delegates to `doGet()`. By the way, have you read the last sentence as well?

In any way, you should basically be performing the very same job yourself.

```
@Override
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    Writer out = resp.getWriter();
    out.write("In Service method");

    if ("GET".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())) {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }
    // Check other methods as well!
}
```

Or just call the `super` method so that it can do its job.

```
@Override
public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    Writer out = resp.getWriter();
    out.write("In Service method");
    super.service(req, resp);
}
```

Or just don't override it at all.

Comment: The best option is ***not to override*** service method.

Comment: Yes, what it is said **Never override service() in HttpServlet!**

Answer (score 1):

Reading the code from [HttpServlet](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java.html) (line 607) will show you why. `service()` is responsible for delegating to the appropiate doXXX method.

You might want to read about plain [Servlets](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/index.html) (or [GenericServlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/index.html)), rather than the subclass HttpServlet. What you'll see in the docs is that Servlets are protocol independent, while an HttpServlet is definitely protocol dependent.

Answer (score 1):

service method of HttpServlet actually checks whether the request is GET or POST.Then, it calls the appropriate method depending on the type of request.